# Powershell - Not able to pass remote session variable back to local system

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Very new to powershell so be gentle... Trying to run a  PSSession on remote system (reading in from list of systems). Then trying to return the value for missing patches to my local system to then export to CSV. I am looking solely for a number to be returned. The value gets displayed in the Powershell window when inside the Invoke-command but then at the bottom of the script nothing is shown. Can anyone offer some advice how I can pass that value back to my system to then be able to export to a csv? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
$array1 = Get-Content "C:\Users\******\Desktop\Server_List.txt"
$ReportResults = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$Searchresult = @()


#parse thru each machine name in 
foreach ($MachineName in $array1)
{              

Write-host $MachineName
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $MachineName 

Invoke-Command -Session $session {
Param($ReportResults)


#Get All Assigned updates in $SearchResult
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$SearchResult = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsAssigned=1 and IsHidden=0 and 
IsInstalled=0") 

Write-Host "total=$($SearchResult.updates.count)"

$ReportResults.add($SearchResult)

} -ArgumentList $ReportResults

Remove-PSSession $session 


} 
$ReportResults # | export-csv C:\Users\******\Desktop\Compprogs\Test.csv -
Notypeinformation
```

Comment: basically the problem is you don't return anything, so there is nothing to return. you should return something from the session, not put something into the session like you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You've to "mark" parameter as `ref`. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref) for further info.

Alternativelly you can return your desired value via `Write-Output`. Example:

```
 $returnValue = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {

     Write-Output "Hello World"
 }

 # $returnValue should include "Hello World"
 Write-Host $returnValue
```

Be aware that when you use `Write-Ouput` multiple times at `Invoke-Command` `$returnValue` will include ALL values wrote to the output steram via `Write-Ouput`.

Hope that helps

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for blazingly fast response.